# Problems including Compass and Importing Compass/Css3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to include Compass into my existing project. Maybe the problem occurs because i have already used sass and scss before in my project.

According to http://compass-style.org/install/ i tried these commands.

```
$ gem install compass
$ cd <myproject>
$ compass create --sass-dir "public/stylesheets" --css-dir "public/stylesheets" --javascripts-dir "public/javascripts" --images-dir "public/img"
```

Seems to be succesful, it creates all the css files.

After that i try

```
compass compile
```

and there are no errors, it lists all unchanged files.

now im trying to use

```
@import "compass/css3"
```

to use all the mixins. apparently there was no compass folder in my project, so i cloned the "compass" folder with the "css" folder from github into my project.

https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/tree/stable/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass

than this error occurs

```
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3.
```

is there something simple i am missing or am i completely on the wrong path?

Comment: use `compass-rails` gem

Comment: like this: sudo gem install compass-rails ?

Comment: did not change anything unfortunately

Comment: `compass create myproject -r zurb-foundation --using foundation --sass-dir "public/stylesheets" --css-dir "public/stylesheets" --javascripts-dir "public/javascripts" --images-dir "public/img"`

Comment: sass/compass version of foundation 4

Comment: so using foundation is necessary?

Comment: i have already so much frameworks and just wanted to add compass to my existing jade,sass,javascript, node site

Comment: yeah i tried it, but apparently i have no zurb-foundation installed

Comment: you can set you css_dir and others in config.rb

Comment: the only thing i want to use is the command @import "compass/css3"

Comment: my exsiting project includes already scss and jade, which steps do i have to take in order to be able tu use those compass mixins

Comment: You aren't *supposed* to have a `compass/css3` directory.  Those files are only supposed to exist within the Compass gem.

Comment: i answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108679/sasssyntaxerror-file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-compass-in-production/23122076#23122076

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
compass watch
```

it is more comfortable than a manual compile.